# Using Pickle with spork?

Tags: cucumber, pickle, spork

[Pickle](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle) doesn't seem to be loading for me when I'm using [spork](https://github.com/timcharper/spork)...

If I run my cucumber normally, the step works as expected:

```
➜ bundle exec cucumber

And a product exists with name: "Windex", category: "Household Cleaners", description: "nasty bluish stuff" # features/step_definitions/pickle_steps.rb:4
```

But if I run it through spork, I get an undefined step:

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

```
Given /^a product exists with name: "([^"]*)", category: "([^"]*)", description: "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2, arg3|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there is an extra config line necessary for `features/support/env.rb` when using spork in order to have Pickle be able to pickup on AR models, a la [this gist](https://gist.github.com/812621):

In `features/support/env.rb`

```
Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
  require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')

  # So that Pickle's AR adapter properly picks up the application's models.
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }

  # ...
end
```

Adding in this line fixes my problem. This is more of a spork issue than guard, per se. I'll update my question...